# Out of Range Issue with a Tuple

Tags: python, tuples, range

I'm trying to make a graph with the last two months of purchases but, I'm getting an "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

The error occurs when I try to populate a list with graph data in this equation:

`this_month[day] = {'y': float(i[2]), 'x': week}`

Here are my queries

```
queryset = delivered_orders.annotate(date=TruncDate('created_at')).values_list('date').annotate(total_price=Sum('total'))
queryset_before = delivered_orders_before.annotate(date=TruncDate('created_at')).values_list('date').annotate(total_price=Sum('total'))
by_state = Order.objects.filter(
    dispensary=request.user.dispensary,
    status=Order.DELIVERED,
).values('state').annotate(sum=Count('id'))
visitor_data = {}
for item in by_state:
    visitor_data[item['state'].lower()] = item['sum']

this_month = [{'x': i, 'y': 0} for i in range(30)]
last_month = [{'x': i, 'y': 0} for i in range(30)]
sales_chart_data_last_month = []
#print(queryset_before)
```

Once I load up the calendar data, I call it here:

```
for i in queryset:
    week =  "%s-%s" % (i[0], i[1])
    day = next((index for (index, d) in enumerate(this_month) if d["x"] == week), None)
    this_month[day] = {'y': float(i[2]), 'x': week}
```

Comment: What is the shape of `queryset`?

Comment: @drum its a 30 day calendar that breaks down into orders by four weeks.

Comment: I meant what is the data structure?

Comment: What is the value of `day` when the error happens? It needs to be from 0 to 29.

Comment: what did you expect to get here? `day = next((index for (index, d) in enumerate(this_month) if d["x"] == week), None)`

Comment: @marat I am getting breaking down the results of the query into weeks. I am showing the total for orders in each of the four weeks of the month.

Comment: @barmar that has no effect on the underlying error.

Comment: You're right. The error is in `i[2]`, not `this_month[day]`, since `i` is a list, not a tuple. So the problem is that `i` doesn't have 3 elements.

Comment: @barmar so, how would I update this equation

Comment: I don't know what `annotate()` does. You need to ensure that all the elements of the list it returns have at least 3 elements.

Comment: In this time annotation notes the date created by list as well as price